# How to fix UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 182342: invalid start byte?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, encoding, character-encoding

I am reading a csv file.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("samplefile.csv",delimiter=',')
```

I got error as:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 182342: invalid start byte
```

If I tried:

```
df = pd.read_csv("samplefile.csv",delimiter=',',encoding= 'unicode_escape')
```

Then, It works but I get unwanted characters like 'AÂ'

Also tried

```
 df = pd.read_csv("samplefile.csv",delimiter=',',encoding= 'ISO-8859-1')
```

same unwanted characters

Comment: have you tried df = pd.read_csv("samplefile.csv", encoding='utf-8'')